# jquery timeout on dropdown menu (hoverintent)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, hover, hoverintent

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$('#nav li').hover(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideDown(220);

    }, 
    function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideUp(220);         
    }
);
```

Hello,
I want to set a "delay" on my dropdownmenu, because the respond time is too fast. When I accidently hover 4times in a row(it slides up and down al the time).
I read and tried the HoverIntent jquery plugin. But I am not able to implement it with this easy jquery menu.

Is there anybody with such experience?
I would really be thankful, I tried to implement it but without success (I am bad at jquery). Please give some hint/code, thank you!

Comment: `.slideDown(1000)`? The number parameter for this method is the duration of the 'transition' (in milliseconds). I don't know if is that what you want. Your question is a bit confuse...

Comment: So what is your desired behaviour? If you move the mouse out and back in should that stop it sliding up and start sliding down from the current position? Or perhaps on mouse _out_ it should wait x milliseconds before starting to slide up, and doesn't slide up at all if another mouse _enter_ happens before x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stop the currently running animation. Try this,

```
$('#nav li').hover(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(220);

    }, 
    function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(220);         
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to prevent the hover function firing to many times.

```
$('#nav li').hover(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(220);

    }, 
    function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(220);         
    }
);
```